# Bamboo - export plans from one Bamboo instances, move them to another Bamboo instance?

Tags: bamboo

Is there a way to export plans from one Bamboo instances, move them to another Bamboo instance? I researched a little, looks they have no plan yet though a JIRA has been raised. I just want to confirm that this is the case, and at the moment there's no way you can export your plans from one Bamboo instance, and move them to another? Another scenario is back up the plans, if your running Bamboo instance corrupted, you can restore the plans from this backup.

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bamboo-questions/How-do-export-import-an-individual-plan-from-one-bamboo/qaq-p/803675
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-19832?_ga=2.108167110.57756773.1550032807-1609212272.1542958766

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday i researched the same thing and find out that it´s possible from bamboo 6.0 and forward with something called Bamboo Specs, you can find out more here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/exporting-existing-plans-to-bamboo-specs-894743917.html